# Simple Text Editor for Desktop Environment

Tags: debian, editors

## Issue

Leafpad is the default text editor for the LXDE Desktop environment designed to be lightweight and simple. Although I like this design choice, there are some additional features available in other text editors (ex: Notepad++ for Windows) that indeed improve productivity:
*in order of importance*

- *spell checker
- *macro: simple rec/play keystrokes
- *info bar: total characters/lines and current position
- bracket matching
- multi-tab
- auto-completion
- syntax highlighting
- code folding

*(*) indispensable*

**Question**
Is there another text editor for Linux still lightweight and simple to use but with the aforementioned features (specially the indispensable ones)?

---

## Follow up

### Mousepad Editor

Following some advices, I've just installed mousepad and it seems that it has only benefits compared to leafpad:

- very easy installation (just `apt install mousepad`)
- lightweight: no need to bloat the lxde install with gnome/kde dependencies
- simple, easy and fast
- built-in (no need to install plugins): status bar, bracket matching, multi-tab, syntax highlighting

However, it doesn't solve completely the original issue since there are still some missing features:

- *spell checker
- *keystrokes macro
- auto-completion
- code folding

---

**Operating System**

- Debian Strech with LXDE
  [debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso)

Comment: (G)Vim fits most of those.

Comment: @muru Mind to mention which one it doesn't fit?

Comment: Most people wouldn't call Vim "simple to use." :)

Comment: @muru Most people wouldn't any kind of terminal software simple to use. But does the GUI version (GVim) as simple to use as Notepad++ for Windows? Or does it still as complicated as the standard vi?

Comment: Somewhere in between. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2458/205. It's still Vim in the end.

Comment: @muru I'm still reading about GVim ... does it has the infobar and the spell checker I've aforementioned?

Comment: This question can't be answered by anything other than personal opinion depending on what one's view of "simple" is. I, for example, would be totally lost with any other editor than Vi, or with an editor with multiple tabs (I wouldn't use them) or some form of GUI front end.

Comment: Probably not by default. But I have, with various settings and plugins, this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYb5m.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJCWF.png

Comment: @muru This is interesting. Is it easy to install? Just execute `apt install`? What are the names of such plugins?

Comment: _simple-to-use_ is subjective when it comes to text editors; and the way that many people label things as "lightweight" is often at large variance from reality.

Comment: An "infobar" for vim is [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline). The spell-checker is bundled as part of vim. There are also grammar checkers, e.g. [vim-LanguageTool](https://github.com/dpelle/vim-LanguageTool).

Comment: @Sparhawk The problem I see with vim is that it is an modal editor. For the moment, I don't think it is worth the time investment to learn.

Comment: @MarkMessa It's definite a steep learning curve, I grant. After a few days/weeks, though, it's not much harder than a normal editor, and then after a few months, the advantages are very clear. But I definitely appreciate that it's not for everyone.

Comment: [ON HOLD] How to migrate this question to Software Recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Notepadqq](https://notepadqq.com/wp/download/) for Ubuntu as an alternative to Notepad++ of Windows. It gave me the equal result.

you can try the same with Debian.

Check this for [Debian Installation](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq)

Comment: Just watched some videos about it. Seem to be the way to go. If it were available via `apt install` would have installed right now. Since this is not the case, gonna take a while to learn how to compile it. BTW, any idea why it is not available at Debian repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Geany](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/geany) IDE as text editor it is simple and easy for use and available from debian repository.

You can get the desired **functionalities** by installing the meta-package [`geany-plugins`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/geany-plugins).

```
apt install geany geany-plugins
```

Comment: I'm still reading about Geany but, so far, it seems to have all the features I've aforementioned. However, it also seems to have a lot more: project management, embedded terminal emulator, basic IDE (compile and execute), etc. Therefore, I'm somehow apprehensive whether it is simple to use it just as a plaintext editor and whether it is really low resource consumption (run on old notebooks).